# HQL like query for long datatype

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to write a hql for like on long datatype field but I'm getting error
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

```
String hql = "SELECT ... WHERE ID like :searchParam";
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("searchParam", "%" + searchParam + "%");
data =  query.list();
```

// ID is of type long

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `Long` to a `String`:

`String hql = "SELECT ... WHERE cast(ID as String) like :searchParam";`